# Inconsistency between how Visual C++ and LLVM handle std::function bodies deallocating their owners

Tags: c++11, lambda, visual-studio-2015

Here is my code for implementing a command queue and the command:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>


using CommandCompleteCallback = std::function<void()>;

class Command
{
private:
    bool m_isStarted;
    CommandCompleteCallback m_completeCallback;

protected:
    virtual void virtualStart() = 0;

    void complete()
    {
        m_completeCallback();
    }

public:
    Command()
        : m_isStarted(false)
        , m_completeCallback(nullptr)
    {
    }

    void setCompleteCallback(const CommandCompleteCallback& callback)
    {
        m_completeCallback = callback;
    }

    bool isStarted() const
    {
        return m_isStarted;
    }

    void start()
    {
        m_isStarted = true;
        virtualStart();
    }

    virtual ~Command()
    {
        m_completeCallback = nullptr;
    }
};



class CommandQueue
{
private:
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Command>> m_queue;
    CommandCompleteCallback m_commandCompleteCallback;

public:
    CommandQueue()
        : m_commandCompleteCallback(nullptr)
    {
        m_commandCompleteCallback = [this]()
        {
            m_queue.pop();
            if (m_queue.size() > 0)
            {
                start();
            }
        };
    }

    CommandQueue(const CommandQueue& other) = delete;
    CommandQueue& operator=(const CommandQueue& other) = delete;
    void push(std::shared_ptr<Command> command)
    {
        command->setCompleteCallback(m_commandCompleteCallback);
        m_queue.push(command);
    }

    void start()
    {
        if (!m_queue.front()->isStarted())
        {
            m_queue.front()->start();
        }
    }
};

class CommandTest : public Command
{
protected:
    void virtualStart() override
    {
        std::cout << "CommandTest::virtualStart" << std::endl;
        complete();
    }
};

int main()
{
    CommandQueue queue;
    queue.push(std::make_shared<CommandTest>());
    queue.start();
    return 0;
}
```

In Xcode and Android Studio this code runs well and prints *CommandTest::virtualStart*. Howerer, in visual studio 2015 community update 2 and 3, the application crashes on line

```
if (m_queue.size() > 0)
```

of the m_commandCompleteCallback.

Output:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.    std::_Deque_alloc<std::_Deque_base_types<std::shared_ptr<Command>,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Command> > > >::_Mysize(...) returned 0xDDDDDDED.
```

My question is: am I doing something wrong and it works on mac by accident, or there is a bug in the Visual Studio?

Comment: can you like shrink it down to the minimum of what is necessary to reproduce this?

Comment: @Hayt
Done. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Just ran this code on [an online compiler](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_gcc). It runs fine on vc++ and clang, but crashes on gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pop` destroys the currently running `Command`.

This `Command` contains the lambda that does the `pop`.  This lambda captures `this`.

You then use `this` on the next line:

```
        m_queue.pop();
        if (m_queue.size() > 0) // here
        {
            start(); // and here
        }
```

which is undefined behavior.  Your other compilers probably copied the `this` pointer into a register and didn't reload it from the lambda, or somesuch.

One approach would be to store a `std::function<void()>const*` for the `m_completeCallback` instead of a `std::function<void()>`.

Another approach (less intrusive) is to do:

```
        auto old_front = std::move(m_queue.front());
        m_queue.pop();
        if (m_queue.size() > 0)
        {
            start();
        }
```

which ensures that the Command object poped lasts until the end of the lambda.

This can still cause problems, because I don't think there is a guarantee that a `std::function` whose lifetime ends during its execution is defined behavior, and this still has the `std::function` running *after* the lambda returns.

One approach is to extend `Command` with `shared_from_this`, and have it extend its own lifetime while it is running in `start()` and `complete()` (basically any spot where it enters arbitrary code that could, through some method, destroy the object).

Now the lifetime of the `Command` object will be longer than the virtual call to `virtualStart`, which makes your code a touch more robust.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What you suggested would work. But I think I found a safer way.

Comment: In the CommandQueue::push I am creating a new lambda every time and passing that into the newly created command. So I removed the m_commandCompleteCallback from the CommandQueue.
From what I can understand, now a COPY of the lambda is sent to the Command and it does not become dangling until invoked.

Comment: @vahg From a quick look, I think that would fix nothing.  The above code copies the `m_commmandCompletedCallback` already.  But I cannot evaluate your new design based off a comment, so cannot be sure.